# Problem with sftp

Tags: ssh, sftp

i am facing issue while ftp using the command file, but i don't face the executing using the manual execution of commands..

i need to ftp while connecting to ssh machine, the command file is available in the tmp directory.

i did with `cd "FtpFolder"` with single quotes , without single and double quotes it does not work

but manual commands work any clue..

### Command

```
ssh username@serverip 'cd /tmp; cat cmd_tmp.txt | sftp -oPort=1234 sftpuser@sftpidadress'
```

### Error

```
Connecting to 111.222.333.1...
sftp> Couldn'sftp> sftp> sftp> sftp>
```

### command file

```
cd "FtpFolder"
mget "YYYYMMDD_REPORT - AUTO SAVE _ 1.TXT"
```

Comment: Have you considered using `scp` instead of `sftp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use get command instead of mget. Sftp do not support mget command. And separate commands with newline

```
cd "FtpFolder" 
get "YYYYMMDD_REPORT - AUTO SAVE _ 1.TXT"
```